# Is reading & writing to an excel workbook from an excel workbook faster using VBA or ADO + SQL?

Tags: vba, excel, ado, dao

I have an excel workbook with several sub routines/functions that do a lot of reading and writing to an external excel workbook. It's almost like the external excel workbook is a database of sorts.

For all the many reads and writes I must do, would it be faster for me to stop using VBA loops and use ADO and SQL SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE statements?

Not sure since this is excel to excel communication here.

Comment: @pnuts I don't have an expert insight as I don't fully understand the technology. I really don't know if there are any efficiency with one verses the other either theoretical or otherwise and wouldn't know how to measure it. Hoping to learn from someone who has torn this all apart already as opposed to building all the analysis and leanings from scratch. It would be a shame to spend several weeks learning ADO and developing a way to convert my code only to find I've completely wasted my time.

Comment: I think it's a valid discussion that I've not found online anywhere else. Humorous that some who have nothing to contribute to the discussion down vote simply because they have no answer.

Comment: This is a specific programming problem. Should I program my routine to pull data using ADO or VBA?  IF you don't know, hush,. What the hell?

Comment: Nope, I want expert insight to know from a technology standpoint which technology is better suited for speed when retrieving and writing lots of data from excel to an external excel worksheet. There are FACTS to be shared, neither you nor I have them so let's stop talking and wait for an expert to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are talking an ADO call using a spreadsheet as your Active Data Object as opposed to exporting to an SQL database yes?

I have tried both and found the difference to be negligible however, in saying that my query was a very simple one as it was just for messing around (i actually used a CSV or TXT file or something with a hint file).

I still believe ADO has a place for Excel to Excel for simplifying the query but I could be wrong. If I do Excel to Excel via straight VBA, I will generally read the data into an array and manipulate in memory then make one update to my sheet, this is the quickest way you can do straight VBA manipulation, more sheet updates slows you down drastically.

Depending on the complexity of your query, it could be considered a little overkill to use ADO but ultimately it's your call, it comes down to what you are most comfortable with. If you are comfortable with either, code up both and do some speed tests. I would be keen to see the results if you do for others wondering the same thing.

Edit: If you are going down the path of doing everything in arrays, remember you can use multiple dimensions in arrays, a spreadsheet is a 2 dimensional with rows and columns, you can have loads of dimensions. Picture this: You have a solar system with a planet with an ocean with a ship with a container with a box with an item that's 7 dimensions but you can manipulate any one item by just knowing the coordinates through the many solar systems and planets and oceans and boats etc etc. There is lots of power in multi dimension arrays and in all honesty the only limit is getting your head around it (make sure you draw out a little map before you begin ;)) To get to an item would be as simple as MyItem(2,4,2,3,4,5,6) if you know you are on solar system 2, planet 4, ocean 2, boat 3 container 4 box 5 item 6.

Comment: They put this topic on hold as "too broad" after you already answered it successfully. Moderation is funny sometimes. Anyway, your answer was perfect. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL is significantly faster for storing and accessing data and it easy to setup using SQL Server Express. It seems you are comfortable using SQL statements and should go down that route. You can download SQL Server [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx)

Basically, in SQL, the software isn't storing all the display properties that excel is. So in Excel, Excel is storing the value, the formatting (100s of different properties) and waiting on you to modify the value. SQL is just storing the raw value and some information like the data type. You can import your Excel sheet directly into SQL and it will set up the columns for you if you leave the headers in.

Comment: I don't get the impression OP wants to move to Sql Server but rather use SQL with ADO which can be used to treat an excel sheet as an "table". The data need to be formatted in a specific way for this to work.